# Online tool to check/validate css

Tags: css

Is this website [code beautify](https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate) reliable to check my css codes in details or are there other tools?

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ for example. Just write css validator in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many websites like the one you've attached in your question and they usually follow the same rules, so I wouldn't be too worried about what you use. I use CSSLint from time to time, http://csslint.net/, which is very strict on the syntax and how you are using your rules.

The most important part of your CSS (in my opinion) should be, how reusable and maintainable your style sheets are, and there are many articles on the web which outline some of the principles you should be using, like https://speckyboy.com/good-bad-css-practices/, and a quick google for CSS practices will reveal many different guides and articles on this.

There are also IDEs with a form of intellisense on the CSS syntax, like WebStorm or Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css), so you don't have to paste your styles to and from a website.

Comment: thanks you for your answer it is certaily useful